# Umbraco PartialView CSS and Javascript in Package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm including some partial views in an Umbraco package that I'm creating, and each of them has their own CSS and Javascript files. When the client imports the package in to their Umbraco project, what's the best way (without the client having to do anything) of referencing these files? There may be several of the same partial view on the same page, so I don't just want to include the import statements within the partial itself, as that would register the same scripts and CSS files for every instance of that partial on the page.

What is the best way of including these files in the project without the client having to add the import statements to their Masterpage?

Comment: Downvoter - care to comment on why the down vote? It's a legit question as far as I'm concerned

Comment: Perhaps store a boolean in the HttpContext.Items

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx

Comment: Good idea Peter. I've found this which may be the correct way - http://umbraco.github.io/Belle/#/tutorials/manifest - but if this fails I'll try your route.